# Why is SONIO Index lower than UK Rates?

Tags: interest-rates

The current UK Rate is 3.5. However, SONIO index is at 3.4269.
What is the reason for SONIO Index being lower than UK Rates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current UK Base Rate is 3.50%, which is what UK banks earn on their deposits at the Bank of England.  That rate is fixed by the BoE. Sonia on the other hand is determined by actual transactions in overnight lending by a variety of institutions including non bank financial institutions.  Because there is currently a lot of cash in the system (excess reserves), there is downward pressure on Sonia as institutions try to invest cash.  The point is that these institutions cannot get the 3.5% from the BoE because they are not banks.